# how to use variable as column name in ggbetweenstats

Tags: r

How could I use variable name in ggbetweenstats? None of these seem to work:

```
xField='Species'

ggbetweenstats(
  data = iris,
  x = xField,
  y = Sepal.Length,
  title = "Distribution of sepal length across Iris species"
)

ggbetweenstats(
  data =  iris,
  x = as.symbol(xField),
  y = Sepal.Length,
  title = "Distribution of sepal length across Iris species"
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `rlang::sym` and the bang-bang-operator (`!!`) you could do:

```r
library(ggstatsplot)

xField <- "Species"

ggbetweenstats(
  data = iris,
  x = !!rlang::sym(xField),
  y = Sepal.Length,
  title = "Distribution of sepal length across Iris species"
)
```

[image]